# C# ServiceReference - The response message does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I've read over 100 articles and answers I got nothing, so hopefully you can help (sorry if I cannot find proper one, even if it exists).

I got a class library (.NET Framework) with 4 Service References to SOAP endpoints. In case it matters - the endpoint is a black box, I just got wsdl and I need to connect there.

The library is loaded by the .exe that I cannot change, so even when I tried to use app.config, I cannot (problem is rather known), because it should be added to .exe config, so I use those references but I create a binding by myself and use ChannelFactory as a proxy to call the web method. I tried those 3 types - BasicHttpBinding, BasicHttpsBinding and BasicHttpContextBinding. All binding properties are the same as in app.config generated by the reference. 
After calling a method from an endpoint I got a message, that is very popular on SO:

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly

But answers for this problem aren't helpful for me as the reason why I'm getting this error, is because of the request that instead of SOAP is a following HTML:

```
<head>
  <script>
    var title = "<title>" + location.host + " - webMethods Integration Server" + "</title>";
    document.write(title);
  </script>
  <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.ico">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border=0><frame src="/WmRoot/index.dsp"></frameset>
<noframes>
  <body>
  <h4>
    Your browser does not support frames.  Support for frames is required to use the webMethods Integration Server.
  </h4>
  </blockquote>
  </body>
</noframes>
```

I tried also creating SOAP envelope by myself and connect to the server directly with no service reference, but I got the same message.

Nevertheless, if I try to connect from SaopUI I get proper response.

**What am I doing wrong?**

@EDIT : adding code as @Tim asked

My code - 2 ways, both responding the same...

1. Way with no ChannelFactory

I call a method from the class of the type of the service from reference (I merged 2 methods, because originally in my code it is divided between creating a client and then opening and calling the method - this is in another part of application, but it works similary to this one):

```
public virtual FindCustResponse FindCust (FindCustRequest customer)
{
    FindCustResponse result = null;
    Services.FindCustomer.findCustomer_WSD_PortTypeClient client = null;
    client = new Services.FindCustomer.findCustomer_WSD_PortTypeClient(FindCustomerHTTPsBinding(), GetServiceEndpoint(_serviceConfigProvider.
    RemoteAddress));
    if (client != null)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
            loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = _serviceConfigProvider.User;
            loginCredentials.UserName.Password = _serviceConfigProvider.Password;
            var defaultCredentials = client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials);
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);
            client.Open();
            result = client.findCustomer(customer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logging
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Opened || client.State == CommunicationState.Opening)
            {
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return client;
}
```

Another way - with ChannelFacotry

```
public virtual Services.FindCustomer.ImyService_WSD_PortType FindCustClient()
{
    var client = new ChannelFactory<Services.FindCustomer.IMyService_WSD_PortType (FindCustomerHTTPsBinding(), GetServiceEndpoint(_serviceConfigProvider.RemoteAddress));
    ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = _serviceConfigProvider.User;
    loginCredentials.UserName.Password = _serviceConfigProvider.Password;
    var defaultCredentials = client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials);
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);
    var proxy = client.CreateChannel();
    return proxy;
}

public FindCustResponse1 FindCust (FindCustRequest1 customer)
{
    var customerresults = _service.FindCustClient().findCustomer(customer);
    return customerresults;
}
```

Bindings that I've tried in both cases:

```
public virtual BasicHttpContextBinding FindCustomerContextBinding()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpContextBinding
    {
        ContextManagementEnabled = true,
        MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text, 
        TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
        Security = { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport },  
        Name = ConfigConstants.FindCustomerBinding                
    };
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    return binding;
}


public virtual System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding FindCustomerHTTPsBinding()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding
    {
        TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard, // tried both - with and without
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
        Security = { Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport }, 
        Name = ConfigConstants.FindCustomerBinding
    };
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    return binding;
}

public virtual BasicHttpBinding FindCustomerBasicBinding()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
    TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    Security = { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport },
    // Tried alsow with: TransportWithMessageCredential, Message = { ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName}         
    Name = ConfigConstants.FindCustomerBinding,
    };
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    return binding;
}
```

This is how I get the endpoint address:

```
public virtual EndpointAddress GetServiceEndpoint(string address)
{
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(address, UriKind.Absolute)) {return null;}
    var uri = new Uri(address);
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri.AbsoluteUri);
    return endpoint;
}
```

And my generated app.config (which I don't use as I mentioned) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_GET_Binder">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_GET_Binder1"/>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_ADD_Binder">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_ADD_Binder1"/>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_UPDATE_Binder">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_UPDATE_Binder1"/>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_FIND_Binder">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="SomeBindingname_FIND_Binder1"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://myServiceAddress:11111/ws/veryLongNameGETCustomer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeBindingname_GET_Binder" contract="GetCustomer.getCustomer_WSD_PortType" name="getCustomer_WSD_Port"/>

            <endpoint address="https://myServiceAddress:11111/ws/veryLongNameAddCustomer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeBindingname_ADD_Binder" contract="AddCustomer.addCustomer_WSD_PortType" name="addCustomer_WSD_Port"/>

            <endpoint address="https://myServiceAddress:11111/ws/veryLongNameUpdateCustomer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeBindingname_UPDATE_Binder" contract="UpdateCustomer.updateCustomer_WSD_PortType" name="updateCreateCustomer_WSD_Port"/>

            <endpoint address="https://myServiceAddress:11111/ws/veryLongNameFindCustomer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeBindingname_FIND_Binder" contract="FindCustomer.findCustomer_WSD_PortType" name="findCustomer_WSD_Port"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code - specifically where you create the binding and channel and how you call the method.

Comment: Just shortly: 

I've tried 2 methods - 1. was creating a proxy as client.CreateChannel() with the client as ChannelFactory<interface taken from service reference> and second one with creating class of client from service reference and using client.Open(). In both cases I used ClientCredentials that I added to the client instead of default one. Then I just call a method from the service reference using created proxy/client. Both has the semae response... 

If it helps you, I will post the code later during the day, when I have my machine running.